# how do I compare two attributes from two different table and return multiple columns

Tags: oracle

From the following tables I want to find the salesperson and
customer who belongs to same city and finlly Return Salesman, customer name and city

Here is the table that I created

Salesman table

```
create table salesman
  2  (salesman_id int,
  3  name char(50),
  4  city char(50),
  5  commission float);
```

rows inserted in salesman table

```
insert all
  2  into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)values(5001,'James Hoong','New York',0.15)
  3  into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)values(5002,'Nail Knite','Paris',0.13)
  4  into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)values(5005,'Pit Alex','London',0.11)
  5  into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)values(5006,'Mc Lyon','Paris',0.14)
  6  into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)values(5007,'Paul Adam','Rome',0.13)
  7  into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)values(5003,'Lauson Hen','San Jose',0.12)
  8  select * from dual;
```

customer table

```
create table customer
  2  (customer_id int,
  3  name char(50),
  4  city char(50),
  5  commission int);
```

Rows in customer table

```
insert all
  2  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3002,'Nick Rimando','New York',100)
  3  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3007,'Brad Davis','New York',200)
  4  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3005,'Graham Zusi','California',200)
  5  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3008,'Julian Green','London',300)
  6  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3004,'Fabian Johnson','Paris',300)
  7  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3009,'Geoff Cameron','Berlin',100)
  8  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3003,'Jozy Altidor','Moscow',200)
  9  into customer(customer_id,name,city,commission)values(3001,'Brad Guzan','London',null)
 10  select * from dual;
```

Comment: As an aside, it would virtually never make sense to store names and cities as `char(50)` rather than `varchar2(50)`.  You're wasting a bunch of space by forcing Oracle to store blank-padded strings and you will almost certainly run into problems down the line when someone tries to run a query that compares a name to a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a pretty simple `INNER JOIN`.

```
select s.name as salesperson, c.name as customer, s.city
from salesman s
join customer c
  on c.city = s.city
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Why don't you accept/upvote the answer, then, @soma?